# How to pass user name & password in the URL

Tags: http, url, url-rewriting, web

We have a long vendor list, each vendor website has it's own user name and password, we wanted to make a list of URLs, so one employee can click on one of the URL, s/he can directly log in to the vendor website without has to type the log-in details.

I tried to copy the location with the parameter passed (including username & password) from firebug, but that didn't work, which it redirect me to the log-in page, is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Most likely this won't be possible unless the website is passing the passwords in plain text with a GET request instead of post under https.

Comment: I highly doubt any website that has been secured properly is going to allow you to login by passing a plain text url.  Better yet, why would you ever want to store these url's for anyone to sniff?  Anyone looking at your network traffic would now have all of your username's and password's to the vendor's websites.  How would this be a good security practice at all?!?

Comment: Try [LastPass](http://lastpass.com). It is a free and secure service that makes auto-logging into a website simple, much like you are wanting to achieve.